# What is incorrect in my guessing game code?

Tags: python

It says: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

here's an image of my code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9XzK.png

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Comment: It told you exactly what the problem is.  Look at the line with the `while` loop.  The indentation level is zero.  Now look at the line with `if out_of_guess:`.  The indentation level is one.  It needs to be zero, as does the indentation level of the `else:` that follows it.  Undertstand?  It's exactly what Python told you when you tried to run it.

Comment: This seems like nothing more than a typo, so voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Your last if/else statement is not indented properly highlight it and pull it back one character space. Pull the whole block back